# How to avoid creating form element stays even after the submission?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to make elements by matching the condition.But when i execute the other,the previously created element is stays there.How to avoid such repetition using java script?[image: this is what i am getting]
i have Javascript function Like this:

```
 function maketext(p) {

        var f = document.createElement('form');
        f.setAttribute('method', "post");
        f.setAttribute('id', "update");
        f.setAttribute('action', "updateprod");

        if (p == "Code") {

            var inp = document.createElement('input');
            inp.setAttribute("placeholder", "Type Here");
            inp.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
            inp.setAttribute("id", "mcode");
            inp.setAttribute("name", "mcode");
            var sub = document.createElement("input");
            sub.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            sub.setAttribute("value", "submit");
            sub.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");

            f.appendChild(inp);
            f.appendChild(sub);
            document.getElementById("mys").appendChild(f);

        }
        if (p == "Name") {
            var inp = document.createElement('input');
            inp.setAttribute("placeholder", "Type Here");
            inp.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
            inp.setAttribute("id", "mname");
            inp.setAttribute("name", "mname");
            var sub = document.createElement("input");
            sub.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            sub.setAttribute("value", "submit");
            sub.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");

            f.appendChild(inp);
            f.appendChild(sub);
            document.getElementById("mys").appendChild(f);
        }
}
```

**Html**

```
    <a href="#" onclick="maketext('Code')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Edit</a>

<a href="#" onclick="maketext('Name')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating the elements remove all previous elements from the `div`

```js
function maketext(p) {
  document.getElementById("mys").innerHTML = ''
  // rest of the code
}
```